# Include form tag only in master page if content page not contains <form> tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, master-pages

I am using `<asp:ScriptManager>` and `link` in master page which require `<Form>` tag but issue is here that i have included already `<form>` tags in all the child content pages.

I know i just need to include `<form>` tag just in master page and remove from all child pages but unfortunately its not possible because there are so many content child pages which connected to this master page and also each child `<form>`  tags contains different classes like `horizental` `inline` etc.

So i just want that i just want to include `<form>` tag only in master page if `form` tag not exist in content/child page.

If i use both in master and child/content, its showing error, its must 1 form tag.

Master page

```
<form id="Form2" runat="server" novalidate="" role="form" runat="server" class="form-horizontal">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <h3>Session Idle:&nbsp;<span id="secondsIdle"></span>&nbsp;seconds.</h3>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake" runat="server" />
    <cc1:modalpopupextender id="mpeTimeout" behaviorid="mpeTimeout"
        runat="server" popupcontrolid="pnlPopup" targetcontrolid="lnkFake"
        okcontrolid="btnYes" cancelcontrolid="btnNo"
        backgroundcssclass="modalBackground" onokscript="ResetSession()">
     </cc1:modalpopupextender>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
        <div class="header">
            Session Expiring!
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            Your Session will expire in&nbsp;<span id="seconds"></span>&nbsp;seconds.<br />
            Do you want to reset?
        </div>
        <div class="footer" align="right">
            <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="yes" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnNo" runat="server" Text="No" CssClass="no" />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="body" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

I just want to use `form` tag only if not in child page. how can i tackle this situation,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the `ASP.NET` `WebForms` do not support multiple `form` elements with `runat="server"` attribute. So, there is no work around to this as it is something hard coded into the project.

**Anyhow**, if there are suppose a thousand child pages that also have `form` element with `runat="server"` attribute, and you are too lazy to replace all of them one by one, *Then* you can use `Visual Studio`'s text replacing feature and can change the `form` element to a `div` element. For that you just need to press `Ctrl` + `H` which will open a little window on top right corner asking for the text that you want to replace and another text that you want to have instead of that. See:

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Notice in the screenshot I have shared, I am selecting *Current Project* from the drop down menu. This will search and replace every text with `<form` to `<div` in the project.

And once it has replaced all the tags starting with `<form` to `<div` then you can modify the closing text of the `form` tag by replacing `</form` with `</div`. Now you only have left one page.
[image: Second Sample Screenshot]

Now, there is only the `MasterPage` left that you can replace back the `div` to `form`. So, this way you are manually changing only one page.

You need to click the second button that will replace all the values. There are other options to handle the find and replace that you can use as well. But, unfortunately, you cannot have multiple `form` tags with `runat="server"` attributes on it.

**PS**
It won't cause problem with the designs that you have and classes such as `horizontal inline` will be applied to those `divs` instead of `forms` and will be rendered same as the `forms` were being rendered on the UI.

*It is always a good approach to take a `backup` before modifying things in bulk or changing something that is crucial and could cause a lot mess.*